# $injector:modulerr error in IE 11 Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

I've developed an AngularJS App and it works on Firefox,Opera,Safari, Edge, and Chrome but it won't work on IE 11.

Here is the specific error message I get in opening the app in IE 11:

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TicketSystemApp due
>   to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   TicketSystemControllers due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'TicketSystemControllers' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it.

It seems like my module app is not loading.

Here is my entire script load:

```
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!-- Angular js -->
<script src= "js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/toArrayFilter.js"></script>
<!-- auto-scroll module  -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js"></script>

<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
<!-- Controllers -->
<script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src ="js/globalFunctions.js"></script>
<!-- Custom File Upload Angular -->
<script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
<script src="js/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<!-- FACTORY -->
<script src = "js/authInterceptor.js"></script>


<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/session.js"></script>

<!-- loading bar -->
<script  src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
```

I have this in as my html tag:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="TicketSystemApp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" class="ng-app:TicketSystemApp" id="ng-app">
```

And I do have this in my head tag:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I have tried manually bootstrapping but I just get the same error message twice.

Here is my app.js(Just the initialization):

```
    var TicketSystemApp = angular.module('TicketSystemApp',[
    'ngRoute',
    'TicketSystemControllers',
  'angular-loading-bar',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngMaterial',
  'md.data.table',
  'angular-toArrayFilter'
]);
```

Here is my controller.js(just the initialization).  I use this to module to contain all controllers:

```
var TicketSystemControllers = angular.module('TicketSystemControllers',[
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'md.data.table',
    'bootstrapLightbox',
    'luegg.directives'

    ]);
```

Comment: We can't actually diagnose anything if you don't show us your JS. Please include the source for `TicketSystemApp`, and consider trimming out all the extra HTML/JS tags that aren't relevant.

Comment: Also use the non-minified version of angular.js while debugging so you can get more detailed error messages.

Comment: Harris, I've included my app.js.  Lex, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @KentaGoto When you mark this as an Internet Explorer issue, is that because you've only tested it in IE, or does it actually work in other browsers?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein I've tested and it works in all other modern browsers.  This error message is very specific to IE.  Same code, no error messages in console in the following browsers: Firefox,Opera,Safari, Edge, and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Kenta, it looks like you are not actually creating a controller at all. What you have done is created two modules, is that your intention? If so that is fine but you need to readjust your scripts and make sure you clear cache. IE 11 has an atrocious caching problem. Your scripts should be ordered this way

```
<script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
```

Also I noticed you have a global functions file. That file should be first if you have anything in the other two files that reference it. I suggest setting your scripts like this.

```
<script src= "js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/dist/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="js/md-data-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/toArrayFilter.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
<script src="js/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script  src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>


<script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
<script src ="js/globalFunctions.js"></script>
<script src="js/auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/session.js"></script>
<script src = "js/authInterceptor.js"></script>
```

I don't know if this is the exact order unless I see all of your JS but I assume this is pretty close. Usually you want all files your create in the correct order at the bottom of your  and all vendor/3rd party files at the top in the correct order.

Comment: That is correct Ohjay44, it is my intention to create a separate module to manage multiple controllers.  I was advised to do this when starting this app.  You are seeing ALL of my scripts.  If I copy and paste your code, it will not only not work in IE 11, but it will not work in all modern browsers.  I have tested it both ways, where controller.js is loaded before and after.  Either way I get the same error.

Comment: Kenta the errors you are recieving are due to the scripts being miss ordered. Unfortunately without seeing the over all picture and knowing whats  the intentions of each custom script are it makes it difficult to debug for someone on the outside. As far as using a separate module for controllers, I would advise against that, I would also direct you to go more of the directive route than controller route. AngularJS is intended to work as components(directives).

Comment: Kenta can you please tell me if globalFunctions, auth, session, and authInterceptor have any dependencies? Also are they using the module from app.js or controllers.js? if so they need to come after controller and app and I can adjust my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks Ohjay44.  I am using custom directives, I am just injecting multiple partials each of which has its own controller.  I think you are definitely right about the scripts.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: globalFunctions.js -> app.js.  authInterceptor -> app.js.  auth.js -> app.js. session.js -> app.js

Comment: I readjusted the scripts so that global, auth, authInterceptor and session come after app since they are relying on app.js to be loaded. See if you still get an injector error. If so then you will just need to rearrange your dependencies appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You load the controller before you declare the angular module

```
<script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
```

If you change the order to

```
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
<script src = "js/controllers.js"></script>
```

it should works.

Maybe the same with `toArrayFilter.js`?

**You have to be sure, that the module definition is made before you load some controllers, directives or factories!!!**

Comment: It was like that previously.  I think It does have something to do with the order of the scripts but I can't figure it out.  I have been moving things back and forth.  Same error though

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was using **const** val = something.
When I changed it to **var** val = something, the error was gone.